# calculate difference between time from 2 tables and column have datatype as smalldatetime and time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, time, ssrs-2008

I have 2 table In and shift.
Shift table is like

```
Starttime   |   Endtime     |   shift   |
---------------------------------------------------------       
07:00:00.00 |   16:00:00.00 |   1   |
```

In table is like

```
In          |   Out         |   shift   |   
------------------------------------------------------------
2016-07-01 06:54:00 |   2016-07-01 17:03:00 |   1   |
```

I want to calculate the difference between starttime and out something like

```
Output  
------  
01.03
```

01.03 is the difference of time between end time and the out time.

I wanted to do it in SSRS and when I am doing this in the output field it is giving me an error

```
=Fields!out.Value-Fields!endtime.Value
```

Can we do it using SQL query?

`Endtime` datatype is time and `out` datatype is smalldatetime

Comment: Can you explain how the difference is `1.03`?  This is not obvious.

Comment: endtime is 16:00:00 and out time is 17:03:00

Comment: I'm not sure your question has enough information to answer it.  Does the shift table really only have one row?  If not, how is the row chosen.

Comment: @GordonLinoff its just a scenario, i have many rows in shift table

Comment: I want to understand how we can calculate the difference in time when we have 2 different data type

Comment: Look up TIME()... And / Or Cast() and Convert(). Do the subtraction after they are both in the same data type.

Comment: In your sample data, there is also a difference between shift start time and in time. Shouldn't that be a part of the output? (`-0.06`, `1.03`)?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I am not worried about the intime, I just want to calculate the difference in outtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (Out-Endtime) in your SQL query to calculated required difference, based on table structure provided by you, your query should be like as given below :

```
SELECT *,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(Out-Endtime),108)DIFF FROM tblIN I JOIN tblShift S ON I.shift=S.shift
```

Result

```
Starttime           Endtime            shift    In                   Out               shift    DIFF
07:00:00.0000000    16:00:00.0000000    1       2016-07-01 06:54:00 2016-07-01 17:03:00 1       01:03:00
```